# How can a stateful ejb/container know that the current client is a prev client?

Tags: java, ejb

a stateful will always serve the SOME client, this is the EJB doc says.

In a web application, we use cookie or jsession to know that some client is a prev client.

How the stateful ejb/container knows that some client is the prev client ?

Answer (score 4):

> How the stateful ejb/container knows that some client is the prev
>   client ?

It doesn't. The client has to hold a reference to the stateful EJB along all the invocations of a stateful conversation.

The fact that makes an EJB stateful is it's ability to hold state during many invocations done by the same client, not it's (inexistent) ability to recognize a client that made an invocation previously.

For a stateless EJB you can also hold a reference, but that reference does not guarantee to hold the state between two invocations.

I quote from http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjg.html

> A stateless session bean does not maintain a conversational state with
>   the client. When a client invokes the methods of a stateless bean, the
>   bean’s instance variables may contain a state specific to that client
>   but only for the duration of the invocation. When the method is
>   finished, the client-specific state should not be retained. Clients
>   may, however, change the state of instance variables in pooled
>   stateless beans, and this state is held over to the next invocation of
>   the pooled stateless bean. Except during method invocation, all
>   instances of a stateless bean are equivalent, allowing the EJB
>   container to assign an instance to any client. **That is, the state of a
>   stateless session bean should apply across all clients**.

Comment: for a stateless ejb, we also hold a reference. is it mean that for a stateless ejb although we hold a reference, but in the ejb side, we could invocation different instance ?